# Is it normal for a MySQL create table statement to include redundant collation declarations for every char, varchar, and text column?

Tags: mysql, database-design, collation

When running `` SHOW CREATE TABLE `my_table`; ``, I notice that `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is shown for every `char`, `varchar`, and `text` column in the table. This seems a bit redundant since the collation is already declared in the *table_option* portion of the create statement.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `my_table`;
| Table    | Create Table
| my_table | CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
...
  `char_col_1` char(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `varchar_col_1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `varchar_col_2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `varchar_col_3` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `text_col_1` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1816178 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This behavior is noticeable in both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0 and therefore most likely in other versions as well.

Is this behavior normal and acceptable, or is it a symptom of something that is misconfigured either with the table, database, or MySQL instance?

On the other hand, since collation can be individually set for any specific column, perhaps it is better to explicitly display the collation for every column to avoid any ambiguity or assumptions, even in cases where the collation of the column matches the collation of the table?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that just means that either whoever created the table specified the character set and collate values when the column was created or specified them later with an alter statement. Those values are independant of the database's global variables and would remain set how they are even if the character_set_* and collation_* variables were changed.

Comment: I tested this on a variety of Oracle, Percona, and MariaDB versions.  Only Percona 8.0 showed the redundant info.  (This disagrees with your observation, and my memory of things.  So it remains a mystery in my book.)

Comment: @Rick James How does this disagree with my observation? I only tested this on MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have touched only the tip of the iceberg.

- I think the settings on the table are just defaults for columns that are defined without charset or collate.
- Ditto for `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` -- will inherit from the table defaults.
- I think that the column settings are put into the `information_schema.COLUMNS` table and that won't change with an `ALTER TABLE .. MODIFY COLUMN ..`

Similarly, the *table* charset and collation inherit from the *database* definition, and will be frozen as the table is defined.

About defaults:

- The old default charset was `latin1`
- The current default is `utf8mb4`; this is unlikely to ever change in the future.
- Every collation applies to exactly one charset, and the charset name is the beginning of the collation name.
- Each charset has exactly one "default" collation:  `latin1_swedish_ci`, `utf8_unicode_ci`, `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, etc.
- That default collation (for a given charset) has rarely, if ever, changed.  Perhaps the only change has been for utf8mb4 between 5.7 and 8.0??

(The more I experiment, the less certain I am about all this.)

Best practice:  Always explicitly set `CHARSET` and `COLLATE` for each string column.

Secondary considerations:

- Use `utf8mb4`, if available, for most string (`VARCHAR` / `TEXT`).
- Use the latest available collation (Unicode keeps improving it); currently `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.
- Use `ascii` for things that are clearly only ascii -- country-code, postal_code, hex, etc.  Mostly these can use `CHAR(..)`
- Use `ascii_general_ci` or `ascii_bin`, depending on whether you need case folding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is redundant to have `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` the same in a table definition and a column definition.

Having explicit column definitions means that anyone changes the table definitions of `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION` the column will remain identical.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the _table_ definition of collation is not a "default" like the charset, but rather the actual value unless overridden?

Comment: Ooh, inherits table charset/collation on column creation, or refers to table charset/collation if not defined on column. I'm not sure and that is important. I was always assumed charset/collation behaved identically.

Comment: One test would be `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..` without charset/collate provided.  (I think this will show inheritance.)  Another would be to ALTER TABLE .. CHARSET=.. COLLATE=..` and see if any columns changed.  (I think they won't.)